# Using Laravel's user MYSQL Table for a React-native login

Tags: php, android, laravel, react-native

I'm trying to create a Android/iOS login form with React-Native.

The login form has been created however the issue i'm having now is that the password of the user is hashed via Laravel.

Is there anyway to unhash (if thats even the word for it) the password to check if the filled in password on the app is equal to the Laravel user password?

Thanks,

Mario Eekma

Comment: Laravel  Hashing a Password Using Bcrypt. https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/hashing

Comment: So if i'm not mistaken, i could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt this package.. And use bCrypt.Compare on the raw user input and the hashed password from the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel uses Hash function to encrypt their password .
Since hash is a one way function i.e It can only be encrypted not decrypted. So there is no way to decrypt the laravel hashed password .
However if you want to check for inserted password then built in function of the laravel for checking the hash password matches or not .

```
if (Hash::check('password', $hashedPassword)) {
// The passwords match...
}
```

If you are going to implement the login system with laravel and react native then my suggestion for login would be by creating [JWT](https://jwt.io/introduction/)

Comment: Can i do this without changing anything laravel related? as the laravel application is already fully working

Comment: You need to create an api to handle authentication where you send the username and password to the laravel and by using laravel it verify it and sends something in response for whether the authentication is verified or not . Creating api is only option for validating the use credential

Comment: Yes yes, i know but i mean i can leave laravel's login form and authentication as it is right now right?

Comment: If are creating the login form with react native then you can leave the laravel  login form as it is it and create a separate api which handles the authenticaiton

Comment: Alright! I'll try to make it work :) Thanks for the info!